# SchemaRegistryClient not found when using ProtobufConverter in Kafka Connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm able to stream data out of a database into a Kafka topic using debezium and Kafka connect. I can do so successfully using org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter or org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter.

However, if I try to output using

```
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://my-schema-registry
```

I get

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/confluent/kafka/schemaregistry/client/SchemaRegistryClient
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.SchemaRegistryClient
```

Alternatively, if I use

```
value.converter=com.blueapron.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter
value.converter.protoClassName=myClassName
```

I get

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Proto class myClassName not found in the classpath
```

Any ideas? I've tried putting the kafka-schema-registry-client jar and a jar containing myClassName in the plugin directory, but neither get picked up as plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a Kafka installation downloaded from Apache. I switched to the complete Confluent Platform installation from Confluent and it worked.

Comment: The other solution is to use `confluent-hub` with Apache Kafka to install the necessary components rather than grab indivdual JAR files across multiple projects